# 500 Internal Server Error instead of: 404 - Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Apparently these lines in my .htaccess cause the server to output a 500 instead of a 404 error which should appear when trying to access a non-existant site.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite requests to /de or other real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|scripts)
# Rewrite incoming requests to their equivalent behind /de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Alas I'm very unfamiliar with .htaccess. Where's the mistake in this one which causes the 500 instead of the 404 error?

This is the error in the logfile:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

**Edit:**

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]`

This part is responsible for the error. Why does it prevent the 404-error page though?

Comment: Seems that you've produced an infinite rewrite loop or something similar.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. That error should be caused by the .htaccess above because without it, the error does not occur. But how to fix thix?

Comment: I'm no `mod_rewrite` expert at all; I would try [reading the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/) and comment out all lines then start commenting in line by line until it breaks. To quote: "_The great thing about mod_rewrite is it gives you all the configurability and flexibility of Sendmail. The downside to mod_rewrite is that it gives you all the configurability and flexibility of Sendmail._"

Comment: I edited the problematic section into the starting post. I hope someone can help me fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

> This part is responsible for the error. Why does it prevent the 404-error page though?

The reason why this isn't producing a 404 error page is because of the conditions which prevent the blind match from being rewritten to `de/`.

These are the 3 preventative conditions you have:

```
# these prevent rewriting if the URI doesn't point to a resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# this prevents scripts from being rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|scripts)
```

However, nothing is preventing a rewrite if, for example, `/de/blahblah` doesn't exist. Thus if someone requests `/blahblah`, this is what happens:

1. URI = `/blahblah`
2. checks first condidion: `blahblah` is not a directory
3. checks second condition: `blahblah` is not a file
4. checks third condition: `blahblah` isn't a css or script
5. rewrites to `/de/blahblah`
6. Rewrite engine loops, URI = `/de/blahblah`
7. checks first condidion: `de/blahblah` is not a directory
8. checks second condition: `de/blahblah` is not a file
9. checks third condition: `de/blahblah` isn't a css or script
10. rewrites to `/de/de/blahblah`
11. etc. etc.

You need to add an additional set of conditions to rewrite *IF* the target exists:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/de%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/de%{REQUEST_URI} -d
```

Thus, you should have something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite requests to /de or other real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|scripts)
# make sure rewrite target actually exists as a file or directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/de%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/de%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# Rewrite incoming requests to their equivalent behind /de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This way, a 404 will get returned because nothing is ever rewritten into the `de/` directory.